# How to have ActionBar like Google Play in pre HoneyComb devices ( > 2.2)?

Tags: android-actionbar, android, android-2.2-froyo

**Firstly**, This may look like a duplicate question but trust me I have searched all these questions, but couldn't find a suitable answer, yes it is frustrating. Still if you vote to close as duplicate please post comment so that I can learn,  few of the similar questions are:- 
 1. [ActionBar pre HoneyComb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646169/actionbar-pre-honeycomb)
 2. [Another similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6031774/what-is-the-equivalent-of-actionbar-in-earlier-sdk-versions)

**What I want ?**
In my Application I want to support the ActionBar like Google Play ( with few more buttons ). As shown below,

[image]

I want to use all three Action bars 1. Main Action Bar 2. Tab Action Bar and 3. Bottom Action Bar mentioned in this [design page](http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html).

**What I did ?**  I knew that ActionBar is not supported by default in pre-HoneyComb devices. so I started with searching for Alternatives, so I did following things:-

1. Downloaded the v4 support library and tried to get a working example, but couldn't.
2. Downloaded [ActionBarShelock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) and created an example for that.
3. Downloaded [this](https://github.com/johannilsson/android-actionbar) popular library (here on SO) from gitHub.

I have working examples of 2 and 3, but even they are far from what I desire. However I will prefer not using any prebuild library. Since it is a big Application which requires a lot of dynamic customization.

Please help me by providing any step by step guide to implement ActionBar using support library.

Comment: You can see `ActionBarCompat` sample app in `\samples\android-XX\ActionbarCompat` directory, or see https://github.com/biegleux/ActionBarCompat which adds support for action views. Anyway I would recommend you stick with `ActionBarSherlock`.

Comment: Thnaks,... even if I use ActionBarSherlock how I can get the behavior similar to GooglePlay...

Comment: Can you please share a good tutorial for implementing ActionBarSherlock... their own site doesn't have any... may be I couldn't find... #stupidMe

Comment: Maybe look into the `samples`, also this https://github.com/JakeWharton/Android-ViewPagerIndicator may help you as well.

Comment: @Amit: have you got the solution for this..if yes then plz share .. i also have same doubts

Comment: @Shruti I implemented that using ActionBarSherlock... Which is not exactly like google play but works seemlessly well as per my requirements.... Download it and try http://actionbarsherlock.com/samples.html in case you get any problem in customizing it... feel free to ask.... Good Day,

Comment: @Amit : m unable to import samples in eclipse...is there any other link for getting samples ?

Comment: @Shruti http://www.slideshare.net/androidstream/action-bar-sherlock-tutorial and ActionBArSherlock is very popular library you can get a plenty of samples by just googling ....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After considering that I decided using [ActionBarSherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/), It is really easy to implement and to extend as well...

Comment: Hi Amit, i have added ActionBarSherlock library in my project, my application having action bar & tabs, in portrait mode its working fine, but in landscape mode action bar & tabs are combining into single line, how to stop in single line, please help me.