# actionbar nullpointer exception

Tags: android

I am new to android. My minimum API level needs to be 7, so that I can test the app on my htc hero. My target API level is 17. 
The error concerns the actionbar. Some code is added by eclipse and I guess I need it to propperly run my app on the latest android versions:

```
getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

`getActionBar()` gives NPE on API 7, but not on API 17. How do I solve this without deleting the code (which I will presumably need for modern API levels)?

Comment: as far as I know action bar is added from honeycomb (3.0) aka api lvl 11?

Comment: search for actionbarsherlock

Answer (score 0):

Basically, You need to follow [this](http://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/platforms.html). If You need some good example, I think [Android IO app](http://code.google.com/p/iosched/source/browse/#git%253Fstate%253Dclosed) source might be a good example on how to develop taking care about form-factor, API level etc. during runtime (however, it might be little bit difficult for completely new to android)

Answer (score 0):

Action bar is not supported in any pre-honeycomb versions so any method related to action bar will not get executed....but after searching SO i came across this brilliant thing...

just check this out...

You can find out more information as well as screenshots of sample applications at [link](http://actionbarsherlock.com)

The library is 100% open source and available at [check this](http://github.com/JakeWharton/ActionBarSherlock)

from below question...

[ActionBar pre Honeycomb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646169/actionbar-pre-honeycomb)

Answer (score 0):

i think your device have android version 2.1 thats why you get error.

just add this [actionbarsherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) lib to your Project.

after that just change this line

```
ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

check this tutorials [link](http://dj-android.blogspot.in/2013/02/android-adding-actionbar-navigation-tabs.html) and [link](http://dj-android.blogspot.in/2013/02/android-adding-actionbar-navigation.html)