# Back from launcher icon in ActionBar

Tags: android, navigation, android-actionbar

I am creating `ActionBar` using `android-support-v7-appcompat`. In action bar I have up navigation from logo enabled and its working fine on device with API level 17. But when I run my app on API level 10 device its not working. Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Using following code in activity-

```
private ActionBar ab;
ab = getSupportActionBar();
ab.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

In Manifest file-

```
<activity
 android:name=".History"
 android:screenOrientation="portrait"
 android:theme="@style/Theme.Styled"
 android:parentActivityName=".MainActivity">
```

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646169/actionbar-pre-honeycomb

Comment: It would be nice if you explain the problem with more explanation.May be with a image and full code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`ActionBar` is not supported for below API 11 level.Thats why you are getting error.Read [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) documentation.

To make your code work in lower version, you have to use `android-support-v7-appcompat` instead of `ActionBar`.Read the below blog about how to migrate from `ActionBar` to `android-support-v7-appcompat`.

http://android-developers.blogspot.in/2013/08/actionbarcompat-and-io-2013-app-source.html

**EDIT :**
you can download and setup the support library as mentioned [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html)

Below is my explanation based on your updated code,

-To enable up navigation in beginning in Android 4.1 (API level 16), 
you can declare the logical parent of each activity by specifying the `android:parentActivityName` attribute in the  element.

-If your app supports Android 4.0 and lower, include the `Support Library` with your app and add a `<meta-data>` element inside the . Then specify the parent activity as the value for `android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY`, matching the `android:parentActivityName` 
attribute like below example,

```
 <activity
        android:name="com.example.myfirstapp.DisplayMessageActivity"
        android:label="@string/title_activity_display_message"
        android:parentActivityName="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" >
        <!-- Parent activity meta-data to support 4.0 and lower -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value="com.example.myfirstapp.MainActivity" />
    </activity>
```

For more info read
http://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html
Hope it helps you.

Comment: I am already using android-support-v7-appcompat. sorry I forget to write in question.

Comment: @JohnR: In that case, update your question along with full logcat error.

Comment: Everything working fine. But when I run my app on device with API level 10. Then back from logo icon in action bar not work.

Comment: can you see this link for overflow icon please http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21569347/navigating-up-and-overflow-icon-in-action-bar