# Where to put 'Done' button pre-Honeycomb

Tags: android, android-2.3-gingerbread

I have an app with various screens where the user sets up data then presses 'Done' to confirm. On Honeycomb upwards I have an ActionBar button for the confirmation, but this doesn't exist in Gingerbread etc. Does anybody have any suggestions for an easy way to implement a 'Done' button / what the typical UI for this is?

I can't use the 'Done' button on the keyboard since they're multiline edits which need to show the enter key where the done button would otherwise go.

I'd prefer to avoid adding the overhead of ActionBarSherlock if there's a simpler way.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6646169/actionbar-pre-honeycomb

Comment: Yep, I know about ActionBarSherlock etc. I guess my question is "What would an *actual* pre-Honeycomb app have done?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try [ActionBarActivity](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/app/ActionBarActivity.html) which makes actionbar available on devices up API 7. This [guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) will tell you how to use actionbar(up API 7) .

Comment: I'll accept this answer, since you persuaded me to give in and use ActionBarSherlock. I checked out this Google one but I need API v6, not 7 (and I couldn't get it to work, anyway)

Comment: Thanks.In my opinion,the phone using API v6 is very rare and Google's code may make the app more smooth.